# How to attach to a demonized container in docker

Tags: docker

I can attach to a running container  which was triggered with -t option using below command

```
docker attach <container_id>
```

but i am not able to attach to a demonized container ie  a container  created like this

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 centos
```

Is there any method  to attach a demonized container or ami doing anything wrong.

FYI when i try to attach a demonized container, the process hangs  there and do nothing no log output and if i press ctrl+c after this it kills the deionise container but do not get attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If attach is not working, you could try [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

(that is, if the container is based on an image which includes bash)

That would allow you to open a shell session and see what is going on.